# Cross domain active directory group membership

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, dns, netbios

I have seen a few questions that are like mine, but none that actually apply.  The problem I am facing is:

I need to get group membership of User with:

- Group in Domain B
- User in domain A.
- Service in domain B.
- Forrest to Forrest 2-way trust.

User attaches to service and service gets WindowsIdentity object with SID, name, etc.

In order to get group membership, I am using a UserPrincipal object.  In order to get that, you need a PrincipalContext object.  The constructor for the PrincipalContext object needs the FQDN of the domain (i.e. A.some.domain.com).  The WindowsIdentity object has the NetBios domain name in the username (i.e. A\User), but I cannot see a way to get the DNS name.

Here is an example of code that has the DNS name HARD CODED, that works, but I need to take out the hard coded part.

-- WindowsIdentity wi (passed into the method) --

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "A.some.domain.com");
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, wi.User.ToString());
```

I have another solution that uses impersonation, using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain().Name, but that is not acceptable because impersonation may not be available.  I need a solution that will work with ***TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification***

I have spent several days scouring MSDN and Google (including Stack Overflow) to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does using `WindowsIdentity.Groups` not work? If DomainA\User is accessing DomainB\Service, the user's token should include the groups from both domains.

Comment: Short answer is that this will work.  Just spent several hours testing this.  I was under the impression that the groups coming from the WindowsIdentity.Groups property could be stale or incomplete.  This is true, but it appears that when hitting a service across domain boundaries, the token is always fresh.  Good call.